# Clearing Timeout After Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, function, timeout

I'm currently trying to code something similar to tamagotchi "care mistakes".

In this case, I'm trying to create a function which checks if the object's hunger stat is above or at 10. Once this occurs, a timer will start, and if it remains above 10 after 10 seconds, it'll be logged as a "mistake".

However, if the user does another action which reduces the hunger below 10, it'll clear the timer.

I'm unable to get the timer to clear properly at the moment despite trying the code below.

```
var changeHungerMood = setInterval(mistakeCheck, 5000);

function mistakeCheck() {
    var mistakeTimer
    function addMistake() {
        stats.mistakes += 1;
    }
    if (stats.hunger >= 10) {
        var mistakeTimer = setTimeout(addMistake, 10000);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(mistakeTimer);
        console.log("Mistake Cleared!");
    }
}


minmaxHunger("hunger", 10, 0);
```

At the moment, even if hunger goes below 10 after the check, the timer isn't cleared and it's still logged as a mistake. Could anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: You are redefining the mistakeTimer every time the mistakeCheck gets called. I believe this is where your issue lies. When you run clearTimeout(mistakeTimer) it is therefore not the same Timer that once started the countdown.

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify what you need to accomplish in each case.
Very imperatively, you need:

1. To set your timer if `stats.hunger >= 10`, you're doing it well (except that you declare `mistakeTimer` with `var` two times... skip the second `var`).
2. When the 10 seconds are over, instead of calling `addMistake`, you need to check if `stats.hunger`is still `10` or more, and if it's the case, call your `addMistake` function.

So you need to add a function `addMistakeIfNeeded` that do the check and call `addMistake` if needed. And your timer should call this `addMistakeIfNeeded` function instead of `addMistake`.

And @Jonas is right, you need to put `addMistake` and `addMistakeIfNeeded` out of the `mistakeCheck` function.